# What is the correct usage for this perl script?

Tags: regex, apache, perl, .htaccess

Consider the following perl shell script;

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/index.php?pageid=/p//g' `grep -ril index.php?pageid= *`
```

I am trying to recursively go through all web directories in my site and change any strings of

> index.php?pageid=

to

> p/

This is intended to shorten my links from something like:

> www.domain.com/index.php?pageid=page1

to

> www.domain.com/p/page1

I already have the .htaccess file set up properly, however this shell script is not working for me and I believe it's because of the `?` or the `=` symbol in the original string that is messing up the regular expression.

How might I go about fixing this? I am terrible with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot `.` and question mark `?` are [characters of special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) and need to be escaped. As well, you need to either escape the forward slash in your replacement or use a different delimiter to avoid escaping.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's!index\.php\?pageid=!p/!g'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I must be doing something wrong because by escaping the characters like you explained, the command runs without error but the files that it should be changing are untouched. They have backups created of them but no changes are being made.